# Rights, permissions and groups

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, raspberry-pi

I have a external drive mounted to /media/usbhdd, the owner is: **debian-transmission** and the group is **gebruikers**.

In the group gebruikers i have added the person **debian-transmission** and **pi**. But when i want to change or delete something as user **pi** it doesn't work (i get an permission error).

my /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1   /media/usbhdd  vfat  uid=debian-transmission,gid=gebruikers 0 0
```

With the command id pi i get this:

```
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),101(input),108(netdev),999(spi),998(i2c),997(gpio),115(debian-transmission),1002(gebruikers)
```

And with the command ls -l /media/usbhdd:
total 192

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Aug 30  2014 disk1
drwxr-xr-x 3 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Oct 14 11:42 Network Trash Folder
drwxr-xr-x 2 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Aug 31  2014 shares
drwxr-xr-x 3 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Oct 14 11:42 Temporary Items
drwxr-xr-x 4 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Oct 14 12:26 series
drwxr-xr-x 3 debian-transmission gebruikers 32768 Oct 14 12:26 movies
```

How can i write/change/delete with user pi without changing uid in the fstab file?

**EDIT**
This was the trick:

/dev/sda1   /media/usbhdd  vfat  uid=debian-transmission,gid=gebruikers,umask=0000 0 0

Comment: Could you edit your question to add what `id pi` prints? also an `ls -l` from some file or directory in `/media/usbhdd` would be useful to see what the driver sets as default rights. Anyway, plain `fat` file system maybe does not support everything (?) about unix-like permissions. I know `vfat` has no problems.

Comment: @dave_alcarin I have added the information, it is vfat it was my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the results of `ls -l` inside your device, the group and "others" permissions have the "write" flag cleared. Only the owning user may write.

If you want to keep the mounting ids intact, add a proper `mode` mount option in your `/etc/fstab` to enable write permissions to the group, for example `mode=0775` is `rwx` for user and group, `r-x` for others.

Comment: is this the way to do it? /dev/sda1   /media/usbhdd  vfat  uid=debian-transmission,gid=gebruikers, mode=0775 0 0

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. Remove the space after the comma.

Comment: The command doesn't work, when i reboot the root acount is locked.. if i remove the mode it boots up normally?

Comment: If it does not work, then remove the `mode` option and add the `rw` option, or set the `umask` completely to 0